# When i crank my 94 Chevy S 10 it leaks gas

Tags: fuel-tank

It just happened today. My truck shut off and acted like it was out of gas so i added some gas to it. When i started the truck up it began gushing fuel somewhere between the filler to the tank. Also gas was misting as if filler line was under pressure, when i shut the truck off the gushing stopped and i could see dripping from where filler line meets the tank (there's a metal clamp there). Is there a seal there or something that could cause that?

Comment: Leak on the pressure side of the line from the fuel pump it sounds like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are connections.

One, or more, has cracked chaffed or come loose. This needs to be sorted before it is driven again - either the cracked or damaged pipe needs replacing or the joint needs tightening. Hopefully it will just be a loose connection...

Depending on access it may mean dropping the tank...

Comment: I think it will be fairly easy to get to so i'm going to try replacing the filler line and clamp at the tank, i will post again to let you know if that was it. Thank you for response!

Comment: Sometimes the filler pipe about 2" or just under in diameter, is in two or more pieces - and the joints on that can split.. Good luck.!

Comment: Well it was'nt  the filler pipe, just above the filler pipe was 2 hoses, and one was a gas line. I cleaned it up a little and there was a small hole in the line, i added a little gas and turned the engine over and sure enough gas was spraying out and dripping on the clamp i mentioned. Going to repair it myself. :)